# Logging out from git cli

Tags: git, github, command-line, version-control

How do I sign out from a certain account on git through the command line?

I have two accounts and I don't know how I ended up with the wrong one. And after trying different approaches, I can't seem to find a way to sign out from there.

When I push, I get:

```
remote: Permission to yyyyyyyy/xxxxxx.git denied to ZZZZ. //<---- wrong acc
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/yyyyyyyy/xxxxxx.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I've tried:

```
git config --global --unset-all
```

```
git config --global --unset user.name
git config --global --unset user.email
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git
git push --set-upstream origin <my-branch>
```

```
rm ~/.gitconfig
```

But I always get the same error.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't *sign in* in the first place, so you can't *sign out* either. Instead, each time you run `git fetch` or `git push` (or a command that runs those), Git calls up some other Git over the Internet-phone, using a URL. The URL can start with `https://` (to use HTTPS) or with `ssh://` (to use SSH). If using HTTPS, as you are here, Git will use a *credential helper* to obtain the credentials (user name and password). The credential helper is OS-specific, so mention your OS and Git version.

Comment: git version 2.34.1 and macOS BigSur 11.5.2 @torek

Comment: OK, see [bk2204's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72469584/1256452) and also look into `credential-osxkeychain` as described [on github here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't have the concept of a login.  What it does have is a credential helper that stores credentials, which on macOS is set to the default value of `osxkeychain` in the system config.

[The Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-reset-credentials) explains how to clear the credential helper:

```
echo url=https://github.com | git credential reject
```

Note that if you have two accounts, the best way to handle this for HTTPS is to always place the account in the URL when setting up a remote.  That is, your URL should look like `https://account1@github.com/git/git.git` or `https://account2@github.com/git/git.git`.  Then, because you have different usernames, the credential helper will store the credentials separately for each user and automatically use the right ones.  [This approach](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#multiple-accounts-http) is also outlined in the Git FAQ.

Note that if you need to change the URL for an existing remote, you can do so like so: `git remote set-url origin https://account1@github.com/git/git.git`.